# vim temporary files with native vim on windows

Tags: windows, vim, native, temp

When running a native compilation of gVim under Win7 I have the following in my vimrc:

```
if has ("win32")
  let $TMP="C:/tmp"
  setlocal equalprg=tidy\ --output-xhtml\ y\ -utf8\ --wrap-attributes\ 1\ --vertical-space\ 1\ --indent\ auto\ --wrap\ 0\ --show-body-only\ auto\ --preserve-entities\ 1\ -q\ -f\ shellpipe=2>
endif
```

This should create a temp file. However, after running the command, I see:

```
shell returned 1

E485: Can't read file C:\tmp\VIoC935.tmp
```

The common recommendation for native windows E485 errors is to set the tmp variable, which I have, as you can see from my vimrc snippet. If I remove the let statement, I get a similar result:

```
shell returned 1

E485: Can't read file C:\Users\ksk\AppData\Local\Temp\VIfFA01.tmp
```

In both cases; both directories exist and gVim can write a file to those locations, i.e.,

```
:w C:\Users\ksk\AppData\Local\Temp\VIfFA01.tmp
```

in the current buffer will write this file without error.

Interestingly, while writing this, I found that if I create a new buffer, and delete the original buffer, the equalprg function runs without error (with and without the "let" statement in vimrc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Interestingly, while writing this, I found that if I create a new buffer, and delete the original buffer, the equalprg function runs without error (with and without the "let" statement in vimrc)

That's probably because you use `setlocal` in your `vimrc`

> E485: Can't read file C:\tmp\VIoC935.tmp

I know the reason, but I don't know how to fix it without changing indentation options. The issue is caused by the `'>'` symbol of your indent command, it should work after removing the last part of it or even only the `'>'` symbol. It's so because `'>'` has a special meaning in shell commands. In *nix one can probably just escape it, but this doesn't work for me in Windows.

P.S. I know this is not a full answer, but maybe it will help you solve the issue.

**Update.** Small discussion in the comments discovered that the correct way of escaping is to enclose the last argument in double quotes (the variant `2)` below). So the working command is:

```
setlocal equalprg=tidy\ --output-xhtml\ y\ -utf8\ --wrap-attributes\ 1\ --vertical-space\ 1\ --indent\ auto\ --wrap\ 0\ --show-body-only\ auto\ --preserve-entities\ 1\ -q\ -f\ "shellpipe=2>"
```

Comment: thanks. I understand what you're saying. The caret is the escape character for the dos-command line. Adding ^ to:    if has ("win32")
  let $TMP="C:/tmp"
  setlocal equalprg=tidy\ --output-xhtml\ y\ -utf8\ --wrap-attributes\ 1\ --vertical-space\ 1\ --indent\ auto\ --wrap\ 0\ --show-body-only\ auto\ --preserve-entities\ 1\ -q\ -f\ shellpipe=^2>
endif  made no difference in results. Also, why would creating a second buffer "fix" the problem?

Comment: It should be `setlocal equalprg=tidy\ --output-xhtml\ y\ -utf8\ --wrap-attributes\ 1\ --vertical-space\ 1\ --indent\ auto\ --wrap\ 0\ --show-body-only\ auto\ --preserve-entities\ 1\ -q\ -f\ shellpipe=2^>` (move the caret one character to the right) and I now can't check it at home with Linux. The `setlocal` command sets options for the current buffer only, so all newly created buffers won't be affected by the command (`'equalprg'` should become empty for them).

Comment: That was my first attempt, but '2^>' will error, where as '^2>' will not, (though the original error remains) due to how dos-command globs these special char tokens, or so I've read. If you find differently, I'd love to know!

Comment: OK. I have 3 more variants. They all seem to work in the console, but the first one doesn't work inside Vim for me. 1) `... shellpipe=^2^>`; 2) `... "shellpipe=2>"`; 3) `... \"shellpipe=2>\"`.

Comment: If you want to write up #2 as a proper answer I'll mark it as such. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you too, now I know how to deal with escaping issues on Windows better (and I didn't know about `^` usage in Windows command line before).

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't apply to the original question, but I ran into the same symptoms because of the setting of my SHELL variable within gvim.  I was launching gvim from a Cygwin window, and it picked up the SHELL setting from within cygwin: /bin/bash.  I had to do a ":set SHELL=C:/cygwin/bin/bash" from within gvim, and then the temporary file problem went away.  So check the setting of your SHELL variable within gVim (via ":set shell") when trying to troubleshoot this kind of problem.

Comment: thank you. I had `set shell=bash` in my $GVIMRC because I have mingw installed, and this should be ok, but I was getting an error using `:read! command` because it couldn't read the temp file (in `:echo tempname()`. After about 10 minutes of frustration and searching furiously, I finally ended up here and almost closed out of the tab, but I saw your `SHELL` in all caps, and you saved me a lot of typing. By the way I ****ing hate Windows so much. **** it. **** it. Also, thank you again. </rant>